# Proving that $\lim_{k\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{k})^k = e$

Tags: calculus

Recently, I learned that $\lim_{k\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{k})^k = e$, but I wasn't sure how that is the correct answer. If you plug $\infty$ into $f(x)$, then it will get $\infty$, since $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$, and $(1 + 0)^\infty = 1^\infty = \infty$. But that isn't the answer here. The answer is $e$. Could someone please explain this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: There are ways to link this result to other representations of $e$, but the problem really is that this is actually *the* definition of $e$.

Comment: I do know that this is the definition of $e$, just that I don't know how it actually equals $e$.

Comment: I am just in the process of writing an answer

Comment: Do you understand what a limit is? Because it is far more than simply plugging in infinity and seeing what it equals.

Comment: Well, when you *define* something to be $e$, it (by definition) *equals* $e$. What is *your* definition of $e$?

Comment: @HenryLee Thank you!

Comment: @QC_QAOA A limit is a value that a function approaches when it is "at" a specific value.

Comment: Unfortunately limits can be much more complicated than that, as there existence doesn't just depend on them converging to a value, but a single value. That is to say there cannot be any "path dependency"

Comment: The fault in your reasoning is $1^{\infty}\neq\infty$. Infact, $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form!

Comment: Oh, yes. I see now. $1^\infty = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearing in mind that this could be considered cyclic by some, here is an attempt:
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$$
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)$$
now this limit should be easy to calculate using L'Hopital's rule. Just rewrite as:
$$\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)}{1/x}$$

---

I say this is cyclic as we are using the natural log here, which is actually defined based on the value of $e$. Note another way of doing this would be to do binomial expansion of the function stated and show that it is the equivalent to the infinite summation definition:
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}$$

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just consider integer $k$,
you can show that
$(1+1/k)^k$ is increasing and
$(1+1/k)^{k+1}$ is decreasing
and they have a common limit
which is called $e$.

If you define $\log(x)$
as the differentiable function satisfying
$\log(xy) = \log(x)+\log(y)$
then you can show that
$(\log(x))' = \dfrac{c}{x}
$
where
$c = \log'(1)
$.
The natural log,
$\ln(x)$,
is the one where
$\ln'(1) = 1$.

From
$\ln(x)
=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}
$,
either from the above
or by definition,
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$,
and you can use this
to show that
$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}
=1
$
which is the same as
$\lim_{y \to \infty}y\ln(1+\frac1{y})
=1
$.

Then $e$ is the value
such that
$\ln(e) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your explanation as well!